# get all parents in <ul><li> structure using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the below structure in HTML, which i use to create a tree structure using jquery.

```
<ul>
        <li>Grand Parent
            <ul>
                <li>Parent
                    <ul>
                        <li>child</li></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

every li element has a radio button next to it (not shown in the code, please assume that).

**Now if a select value "Child" from the above code then i should get the below result
"Grand Parent > Parent > Child"
   and  if i select parent then i should get 
"Grand Parent > Parent"**

So basically the i want to get parent with all its child

Please advise how can i get the above result using jquery

***section 1***

```
<ul class='tree js-catTree'><li><a class='expand'></a><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10209'>Business</a><ul><li><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10212'>Top</a></span></li><li><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10214'>New</a></span></li><li><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10413'>Email and Messaging</a></span></li><li><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10414'>Finance</a></span></li><li><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10415'>Mobile Office</a></span></li><li><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10416'>Sales and Field Force</a></span></li><li><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10417'>Calculators  Converters</a></span></li><li><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10418'>Travel  Transportation</a></span></li><li><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10419'>Reference</a></span></li></ul></span></li><li><a class='expand'></a><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10962'>asdasd</a><ul><li><a class='expand'></a><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10964'>asd</a><ul><li><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10420'>Backup  Optimization</a></span></li></ul></span></li></ul></span></li><li><span class='treeNodeInner'><input type='radio' name='category'><a id='10974'>test_23March</a></span></li></ul>
```

thanks

Comment: instead of radio button if i have anchor tag in li then how to get the breadcum path??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Inside an event handler on the element

Put this code inside your event handler to get all parents:

```
$(this).parents('li').add(this).each(function() {
    // This should iterate through all parent <li>s and the current one too
});
```

Try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XPL7G/

### Selecting based on a checked radio button

If you want to select the elements based on which radio button is checked, you can just use the `.parents()` method.

Assuming the following HTML markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="li"> Grand Parent
        <ul>
            <li><input type="radio" name="li"> Parent
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="li"> child</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<button>Show me</button>
```

You can do the following in the button's click event:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var $obj = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').parents('li');

    // The $obj jQuery collection contains your result
});
```

Try a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XPL7G/1/

### Get breadcrumb path as text

As there are nested elements, we can't use jQuery's `.text()` method, as it would return the combined text from all children as well.

The solution is to make an array of our jQuery object, reverse the order, then iterate through them, extracting the text node with raw HTML DOM functions as we go (which assuming the same markup as above is the second child of the list item, the first being the radio button).

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var $obj = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').parents('li');

    var result = '';
    $($obj.get().reverse()).each(function(){
        if(result) result += ' > ';
        result += this.childNodes[1].nodeValue;
    });

    // The variable result contains our text breadcrumb
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XPL7G/6/

Comment: which event handler. I want the result structure on click of a button. Please advise

Comment: @Amit: I have updated my answer with the radio buttons added.

Comment: This works for the above html well, but if i add another li tag inside the main ul tag then this will bring that li as well. updated html below <ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="li"> Grand Parent
        <ul>
            <li><input type="radio" name="li"> Parent
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="li"> child</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li><li> test</li>
</ul>

Comment: that works well i have checked the url. Please can you advise how i cann get the results in following format  grandparent > parent > child

Comment: Do you mean you want to get `grandparent > parent > child` as text?

Comment: it doesn't work for my html which i have added for your reference in my question under "section 1" heading. Please advise

Comment: You just need to change the string building to traverse the DOM tree according to your markup: `result += $(this).children('span').children('a').text();` Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XPL7G/8/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
console.log($('ul :parent'));//return all parent node within first `ul`
```

Comment: if i am using a anchor tag  instead of radio button what should i do??

Answer (score 1):

```
$(‘li’).parents()
```

will list all the parents of that li

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
  var $el = $(this); //current radio
  var $parents = $el.parents('input[type="radio"]'); //parent radios
});
```

Comment: every li element has a anchor tag next to it (not shown in the code, please assume that).

Now if a select value "Child" from the above code then i should get the below result "Grand Parent/ Parent / Child" and if i select parent then i should get "Grand Parent / Parent"

So basically the i want to get parent with all its child

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your intention.
However I think the combination of selector may be what solves it. For example something like this should work:

```
$(':parent li')
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question properly..

Though I think this is what you want :

```
$(somethin).parent().children();
```

Comment: You can combine Matthew's idea to get the "something"